# bokeh selected.on_change not working for my current setup

Tags: bokeh, interactive

Basically, this is an interactive heatmap but the twist is that the source is updated by reading values from a file that gets updated regularly.

dont bother about the class "generator", it is just for keeping data and it runs regularly threaded

make sure a file named "Server_dump.txt" exists in the same directory of the script with a single number greater than 0 inside before u execute the bokeh script.

what basically happens is i change a number inside the file named "Server_dump.txt" by using `echo 4 > Server_dump.txt` on bash,
u can put any number other than `4` and the script automatically checks the file and plots the new point.

if u don't use bash, u could use a text editor , replace the number and save,  and all will be the same.

the run function inside the generator class is the one which checks if this file was modified , reads the number, transforms it into x& y coords and increments the number of taps associated with these coords and gives the `source` x,y,taps values based on that number.

well that function works fine and each time i echo a number , the correct rectangle is plotted but,

- now I want to add the functionality of that clicking on a certain rectangle triggers a callback to plot a second graph based on the coords of the clicked rectangle but i can't even get it to trigger even though i have tried other examples with selected.on_change in them and they worked fine.

*if i increase self.taps for a certain rect by writing the number to the file multiple times, color gets updated but if i hover over the rect it shows me the past values and not the latest value only .

my bokeh version is 1.0.4

```
from functools import partial
from random import random,randint
import threading 
import time
from tornado import gen
from os.path import getmtime
from math import pi
import pandas as pd
from random import randint, random
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper, BasicTicker, widgets, PrintfTickFormatter, ColorBar, ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], taps=[]))

doc = curdoc()

#sloppy data receiving function to change data to a plottable shape 
class generator(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(generator, self).__init__()
        self.chart_coords = {'x':[],'y':[],'taps':[]}
        self.Pi_coords = {}  
        self.coord = 0
        self.pos = 0
        self.col = 0
        self.row = 0
        self.s = 0
        self.t = 0

    def chart_dict_gen(self,row, col):
        self.col = col
        self.row = row+1
        self.chart_coords['x'] = [i for i in range(1,cla.row)]
        self.chart_coords['y'] = [i for i in range(cla.col, 0, -1)] #reversed list because chart requires that
        self.chart_coords['taps']= [0]*(row * col)
        self.taps = [[0 for y in range(col)] for x in range(row)]

    def Pi_dict_gen(self,row,col):
        key = 1
       for x in range(1,row):
           for y in range(1,col):
               self.Pi_coords[key] = (x,y)
               key = key + 1

    def Pi_to_chart(self,N):
        x,y = self.Pi_coords[N][0],  self.Pi_coords[N][1]
       return x,y

    def run(self):
      while True:
        if(self.t == 0):
            self.t=1
            continue
        time.sleep(0.1)

        h = getmtime("Server_dump.txt")
        if self.s != h:
            self.s = h
             with open('Server_dump.txt') as f:
                 m = next(f)
                 y,x = self.Pi_to_chart(int(m))
                 self.taps[x][y] += 1 
                 # but update the document from callback 
                doc.add_next_tick_callback(partial(update, x=x, y=y, taps=self.taps[x][y]))


cla = generator()
cla.chart_dict_gen(15,15)
cla.Pi_dict_gen(15, 15)

x = cla.chart_coords['x']
y = cla.chart_coords['y']
taps = cla.chart_coords['taps']

@gen.coroutine
def update(x, y, taps):
    taps += taps
    print(x,y,taps)
    source.stream(dict(x=[x], y=[y], taps=[taps]))

colors = ["#CCEBFF","#B2E0FF","#99D6FF","#80CCFF","#66c2FF","#4DB8FF","#33ADFF","#19A3FF", "#0099FF", "#008AE6", "#007ACC","#006BB2", "#005C99", "#004C80", "#003D66", "#002E4C", "#001F33", "#000F1A", "#000000"]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low= 0, high= 15) #low = min(cla.chart_coords['taps']) high = max(cla.chart_coords['taps'])

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"


p = figure(title="Tou",
           x_range=list(map(str,x)),
           y_range=list(map(str,reversed(y))),
           x_axis_location="above",
           plot_width=900, plot_height=400,
           tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('coords', '@y @x'), ('taps', '@taps%')])

p.grid.grid_line_color = "#ffffff"
p.axis.axis_line_color = "#ef4723"
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = "#af0a36"
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "7pt"
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None

p.rect(x="x", y="y",
       width=0.9, height=0.9,
       source=source,
       fill_color={'field': 'taps', 'transform': mapper},
       line_color = "#ffffff",
)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper,
                     major_label_text_font_size="7pt",
                     ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                     formatter=PrintfTickFormatter(format="%d%%"),
                     label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))

curdoc().theme = 'dark_minimal'

def ck(attr, old, new):
    print('here') #doesn't even print hi in the terminal if i click anywhere 

source.selected.on_change('indices', ck)


p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

doc.add_root(p)

thread = cla
thread.start()
```

i wanted even to get a printed hi in the terminal but nothing

Comment: Can you update the code to generate fake data? Or make the file available? I'd like to look more closely but can't say anything without running the code.

Comment: @bigreddot if u look at the run function under the generator class, all it does is check if the file "server_dump" existing in the same directory was modified recently and if true then it reads the value inside and updates the source . I on my side echo a number into the server_dump file from bash" echo 3 > Server_dump.txt" and it is plotted as intended

Comment: When I run the code above there is nothing plotted, and a console error reporting the missing data file.

Comment: Just to be explicit: Echoing values to the file does not cause any data to be plotted with the above code. If there is no data plotted, then it is 100% certain that no selection can be made (because there is no data to select), which means I cannot investigate anything. Stack Overflow questions should contain *complete minimal reproducing examples*.

Comment: @bigreddot create an empty file named `Server_dump.txt` in the same directory then put any arbitrary number greater than 0 inside then execute the script and if u wanna plot a new point, replace that number and save if u are using an editor (not notepad) or `echo 4 > Server_dump.txt` if u are using a terminal, replace 4 by any number u like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not actually added any selection tool at all to your plot, so no selection is ever made. You have specified:

```
TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"
```

Those are the only tools that will be added, and none of them make selections, there for nothing will cause `source.selection.indices` to ever be updated. If you are looking for selections based on tap, you must add a `TapTool`, e.g. with

```
TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom,tap"
```

Note that there will not be repeated callbacks if you tap the same rect multiple times. The callback only fires when the selection *changes* and clicking the same glyph twice in a row results in an identical selection.

Comment: what also befuzzles me is that if i echo the same number many times it increases the number of taps and accordingly changes the color for the same rect but when i hover over, it displays all the previous , please check it so u get what i mean

Comment: I have updated the question so it is a bit clear , what i mean by echo into the file

Comment: can u help me with the second issue?
if i hover over a rect, i get multiple values not just one.

Comment: multiple tooltips? or one tooltip that has a list of values instead of one? If the former, you have drawn overlapping rects that are all getting hit by the hover. If the latter, then you have stored a list of values for a single index in the CDS. For this, it's usually helpful to print out the data to debug. Usually you will see what values are not what you expect.

Comment: it is the former, is there a way so i can delete them or even not drawing a new rectangle each time. i am obeying the examples and i am updating the source with values so why is it behaving this way?!!

Comment: You have complete control over what goes on the data source. Bokeh just renders what you put in it. You should print your data to see how it differ's from your expectations.

Comment: i am sorry for nagging but i really read a lot and i couldn't get to a solution.
i know my explanation wasn't clear so i have tried once more and updated the question with more details, plz read it again . first point is answered, i need the second point , thx.

Comment: data doesn't differ , the problem is i update the source from callback so as u pointed it out , it does plot a second rectangle but i want to update the first rectangle or delete it and make a second one but i can't get to the possible way of doing it

Comment: so i found in https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6423 that tools hold references to data irrespective of me changing data so that might be the problem, how i can get to those references